# Combining FacetGrid and dual Y-axis in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, facet

I am trying to plot two different variables (linked by a relation of causality), `delai_jour` and `date_sondage` on a single FacetGrid. I can do it with this code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_verif_sum, col="prefecture", col_wrap=2, aspect=2, sharex=True,)
g = g.map(plt.plot, "date_sondage", "delai_jour", color="m", linewidth=2)
g = g.map(plt.bar, "date_sondage", "impossible")
```

which gives me this:

[FacetGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOV1b.png)

(There are 33 of them in total).

I'm interested in comparing the patterns across the various `prefecture`, but due to the difference in magnitude I cannot see the changes in the line chart.

For this specific work, the best way to do it is to create a secondary y axis, but I can't seem to make anything work: it doesn't look like it's possible with FacetGrid, and I didn't understand the code not was able to replicate the examples i've seen with pure matplotlib.

How should I go about it?

Comment: I disagree with the claim that "the best way to do it is to create a secondary y axis". That is [one of the worst ways](https://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2016/01/16/two-y-axes/).

Comment: thank you for the article. I think there is a misunderstanding: I'm not saying that in all cases a second axis is better. I'm saying that for my case, which is to visually explore the patterns of 2 variables linked by a relation of causality, it is the most space and visually efficient way. But I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: That is exactly the application described in the article. Using parallel timeseries with two axes to show "a relation of causality" can be highly misleading because the extent of the apparent relationship is largely controlled by the arbitrary y axis scaling.

Comment: I'm not trying to find a relation of causality. I know there is one. i'm not comparing the pattern within one graph, but the co-patterns across the 33 facets.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by iterating through the axes and plotting a secondary axis as in a typical Seaborn graph.

Using the OP example:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_verif_sum, col="prefecture", col_wrap=2, aspect=2, sharex=True)
g = g.map(plt.plot, "date_sondage", "delai_jour", color="m", linewidth=2)
for ax, (_, subdata) in zip(g.axes, df_verif_sum.groupby('prefecture')):
    ax2=ax.twinx()
    subdata.plot(x='data_sondage',y='impossible', ax=ax2,legend=False,color='r')
```

If you do any formatting to the x-axis, you may have to do it to both ax and ax2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where you apply a custom mapping function to the dataframe of interest. Within the function, you can call `plt.gca()` to get the current axis at the facet being currently plotted in FacetGrid. Once you have the axis, `twinx()` can be called just like you would in plain old matplotlib plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

def facetgrid_two_axes(*args, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    dual_axis = kwargs.pop('dual_axis')
    alpha = kwargs.pop('alpha', 0.2)
    kwargs.pop('color')
    ax = plt.gca()
    if dual_axis:
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.set_ylabel('Second Axis!')

    ax.plot(data['x'],data['y1'], **kwargs, color='red',alpha=alpha)
    if dual_axis:
        ax2.plot(df['x'],df['y2'], **kwargs, color='blue',alpha=alpha)


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.arange(1,5,1)
df['y1'] = 1 / df['x']
df['y2'] = df['x'] * 100
df['facet'] = 'foo'
df2 = df.copy()
df2['facet'] = 'bar'

df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])
win_plot = sns.FacetGrid(df3, col='facet', size=6)
(win_plot.map_dataframe(facetgrid_two_axes, dual_axis=True)
         .set_axis_labels("X", "First Y-axis"))
plt.show()
```

This isn't the prettiest plot as you might want to adjust the presence of the second y-axis' label, the spacing between plots, etc. but the code suffices to show how to plot two series of differing magnitudes within FacetGrids.

[image: seaborn_double_y_axis]