# Python. Use two y axis for line and bar plots on Seaborn Facetgrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

**Updated question and code!** 
Probably, the tips dataset is not the best example to use, however my issue is reproduced in it, i.e. we see that both point and bar plots share the same Y

I need to combine line and bar plots on one chart. To do this I used seaborn and the following code:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, hue='sex', col='sex', size=4, aspect=2.1, sharey=False, sharex=False)

g = g.map(sns.pointplot, 'day', 'tip', ci=0)
g = g.map(sns.barplot, 'day', 'total_bill', ci=0)

g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45, fontsize=9)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45, fontsize=9)

plt.show()
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Everything is okay except the fact that one Y axis is used for both bars and lines on each facetgrid object. I am new to seaborn and currently cannot find a solution. Tried to add "sharey=False" to this line of code

```
> `g.map(sns.pointplot, 'date', 'worthusdcount')`
```

however it didn't help.

Any solutions on how to add second Y axis would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808566/combining-facetgrid-and-dual-y-axis-in-pandas). From that you may also deduce the fate of this one: Without [mcve] it might not get an answer for 2 years.

Comment: Updated question and code. Recheck it, please @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn FacetGrid plot two different y axis next to eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659771/seaborn-facetgrid-plot-two-different-y-axis-next-to-eachother)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example where you apply a custom mapping function to the dataframe of interest. Within the function, you can call `plt.gca()` to get the current axis at the facet being currently plotted in FacetGrid. Once you have the axis, `twinx()` can be called just like you would in plain old matplotlib plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

def facetgrid_two_axes(*args, **kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    dual_axis = kwargs.pop('dual_axis')
    alpha = kwargs.pop('alpha', 0.2)
    kwargs.pop('color')
    ax = plt.gca()
    if dual_axis:
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.set_ylabel('Second Axis!')

    ax.plot(data['x'],data['y1'], **kwargs, color='red',alpha=alpha)
    if dual_axis:
        ax2.bar(df['x'],df['y2'], **kwargs, color='blue',alpha=alpha)


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.arange(1,5,1)
df['y1'] = 1 / df['x']
df['y2'] = df['x'] * 100
df['facet'] = 'foo'
df2 = df.copy()
df2['facet'] = 'bar'

df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])
win_plot = sns.FacetGrid(df3, col='facet', size=6)
(win_plot.map_dataframe(facetgrid_two_axes, dual_axis=True)
         .set_axis_labels("X", "First Y-axis"))
plt.show()
```

This isn't the prettiest plot as you might want to adjust the presence of the second y-axis' label, the spacing between plots, etc. but the code suffices to show how to plot two series of differing magnitudes within FacetGrids.

[image: seaborn_double_y_axis]